# CSS problemas en equipo Motorola

Tags: css3, devices

Estoy teniendo problemas con mis medias en un equipo motorola z play.

Ya revise en diferentes equipos y si hace el cambio que requiero pero en el motorola es donde no se ve reflejado.

Alguien que pueda ayudarme.

Aso tengo el css, ya hice pruebas de darle mas bottom para que el elemento baje mas pero aun asi sigue sin funcionar.

```
@media  screen and (max-width:370px){
#botonnex {
    position: absolute;
    left: 75%;
    bottom: -39%;
}
```

Ya revise la medida que tiene y lo probe en el simulador de google y se ve bien pero en el equipo fisico no funciona.

El equipo usa google chrome usa la version 75.0.37

Saludos

Comment: serviría mucho a tu pregunta que agregues que navegador ejecuta el dispositivo y además que versión de navegador es la que posee

Comment: @Aprendiz Listo  usa google chrome usa la version 75.0.37

Comment: Validá que el navegador no tenga habilitada la opción "Desktop site" o "Sitio de escritorio" (no sé cómo se llama en español)

Answer (score 0):

Saludos quizá puedes usar algo así:

```
@media screen and (device-width: 360px) and (device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
...
...
}
```

en este caso aplico estilos para un Motorola G, podrias editar tanto el **width** como el **height** para dicho dispositivo.
Adicional no te olvides de tener la etiqueta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

También puedes revisar el siguiente listado de media querys css con distintos dispositivos:
[Media queries](https://gist.github.com/francoishill/6483997)

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Answer (score 0):

Ya intentaste borrando el cache de tu celular, eso podría estarte jugando una mala broma, y en realidad ya se están aplicando tus estilos.

Desde el menú de chrome, en la sección de historial puedes seleccionar exactamente que datos eliminar y así ver si no es eso, revisalo y nos avisas para ir descartando posibilidades.